# What is the cleanest way to see if a nullable type has a value, and if it does, to compare the value to another non-nullable type's value?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have two nullable enums which I would like to compare the value of to two regular enums. If the nullable enums do not have a value, I want the comparison to evaluate to true. This is what my logic looks like so far:

```
if (!nullableEnumOne.HasValue || nullableEnumOne.Value == regularEnumOne) 
    && (!nullableEnumTwo.HasValue || nullableEnumTwo.Value == regularEnumTwo)
{
    //do something
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this logic which I am missing?

Comment: Your parentheses don't match. Please fix this so it compiles and correctly reflects your intent.

Comment: @Dave: The OP isn't trying to compare `nullableEnumOne` and `nullableEnumTwo` at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah yes a very valid point. Apologies I had misread the question

Comment: @Dave: Easy to do, and I've done so hundreds of times before :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably simplest to use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) to "default" to the value that you're comparing against:

```
if ((nullableEnumOne ?? regularEnumOne) == regularEnumOne &&
    (nullableEnumTwo ?? regularEnumTwo) == regularEnumTwo)
```

Or stick with your current code... or compare against `null` instead of using a negative condition:

```
if ((nullableEnumOne == null || nullableEnumOne.Value == regularEnumOne) 
    && ((nullableEnumTwo == null || nullableEnumTwo.Value == regularEnumTwo))
```

Or slightly weirdly, you could call `Equals` with the null conditional operator, using the null coalescing operator to make the null case true:

```
if ((nullableEnumOne?.Equals(regularEnumOne) ?? true)
   && (nullableEnumTwo?.Equals(regularEnumTwo) ?? true))
```

None of these are *massively* readable, admittedly. I'd be tempted to write a helper method, so you can write:

```
if (NullOrEqual(nullableEnumOne, regularEnumOne) &&
    NullOrEqual(nullableEnumTwo, regularEnumTwo))
```

Comment: Everything is better with extension methods :-) 
`public static class NullableExtensions
    {
        public static bool NullOrEqual<T>(this T? nullable, T compareTo) where T: struct
        {
            return nullable == null || nullable.Value.Equals(compareTo);
        }
    }`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'm not sure - maybe in a very limited scope, but I tend to reserve extension methods for generally-useful code. This is pretty specific.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion. To me, it seems that this kind of method is almost begging to be an extension method. IMHO, `NullOrEqual<T>` is much more readable as an extestion method then as a "regular method". Also, I tend to use extension methods even if they are specific to a single project or assembly. As soon as a method needs to be used for the same type in more than one class, I usually consider it as a good candidate to be an extension method.

Comment: As for better naming, I'd prefer the slight modification `nullableEnumOne.EqualsNullOr(regularEnumOne)`